# The selects of a DropDownList with IE11 won't be displayed correctly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I'm facing a bug with my dropdownlists on IE11,

Indeed, when I open it, the select options aren't displayed in the right place.

[image]

[image]

I would like to display the select options below, like with normal dropdownlists.

Thank you for your help

Comment: that is the browser behavior

Comment: This is the default behavior for select element in IE11, in order to bypass it you can try to create you own custom select element.